# Redis Lua script not working as expected

Tags: arrays, lua, redis, lua-table

As a practice exercise, I'm writing a lua script for Redis which basically executes the JavaScript method [Array#copyWithin()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/copyWithin).

Quoting from MDN,

> The copyWithin() method copies the sequence of array elements within
>   the array to the position starting at target. The copy is taken from
>   the index positions of the second and third arguments start and end.

Here is the script I've written so far :

```
local list = redis.call('lrange', KEYS[1], 0, -1)
local target = tonumber(ARGV[1])
local startIndex = tonumber(ARGV[2])
local len = #list
local endIndex = len

--Handle negative startIndex
if startIndex < 0 then
    startIndex = len+startIndex
end

--If the third argument is provided, get the endIndex from it
if #ARGV > 2 then
    local arg = tonumber(ARGV[3])
    if arg >= 0 then
        if arg < endIndex then
            endIndex = arg
        end
    else
        if len+arg >= 0 then
            endIndex = len+arg
        else
            endIndex = 0
        end
    end
end

--An array containing the elements which will be copied
local targeted_elements = {}

--Fill elements from the list
for i=1, (endIndex-startIndex+1) do
    targeted_elements[i] = list[startIndex+i]
end

--Make sure no additional elements are pushed to the end of array in case of range overflow
local target_end = #targeted_elements

if target + target_end > len then
    target_end = len-target
end

--replace all the changed elements of the list in redis
for i=1, target_end do
    redis.call('lset', KEYS[1], target+(i-1), targeted_elements[i])
end
```

During testing, the first test case is successfully cleared :

Test case : `convert [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` into `[4, 5, 3, 4, 5]` using `copyWithin(0, 3)`

```
LRANGE MyList 0 -1
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

EVALSHA "sha1 of script" 1 MyList 0 3
(basically the same as `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].copyWithin(0, 3)`)
> nil

LRANGE MyList 0 -1
> [4, 5, 3, 4, 5]
```

The second test case however, did not go that smooth.

Test case : `convert [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` into `[4, 2, 3, 4, 5]` using `copyWithin(0, 3, 4)`

```
LRANGE MyList 0 -1
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

EVALSHA "sha1 of script" 1 MyList 0 3 4
(basically the same as `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].copyWithin(0, 3, 4)`)
> nil

LRANGE MyList 0 -1
> [4, 5, 3, 4, 5]
```

After some debugging, I found that the value of `targeted_elements` is `{4, 5}` in both the cases, whereas it should be `{4}` in case 2.

Is there anything suspicious in the loops? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by modifying the following part of the script :

```
--Fill elements from the list
for i=1, (endIndex-startIndex+1) do
    targeted_elements[i] = list[startIndex+i]
end
```

Changed it into this:

```
--Fill elements from the list
    for i=1, (endIndex-startIndex) do
        targeted_elements[i] = list[startIndex+i]
    end
```

The `+1` in the `for` expression added an additional element to the array. It worked in the first case because the selected part was from `3, 5`, so `5-3+1 = 3` which means `3` elements should be selected. But since only `2` elements are left, the case still works.

Whereas for the second case, `4-3+1 = 2`, which means `2` elements were being selected, instead of `1`.